# Install and Run Windows Service in C++

Tags: c++, windows, windows-services

I am working on windows services for the first time and after some effort I am now able to Install and unistall a service programatically in C++,
I have found many tutorials which guide on how to deal with
 ServiceMain and ServiceControlHandler functions.
Problem is that there is no tutorial which shows that first we install a service and then in the same program apply ServiceMain and ServiceControlHandler functions.

In short I am trying to integrate both functionalities in the same code but it is not working.

Here are some links I have followed

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/499465/Simple-Windows-Service-in-Cplusplus

http://www.devx.com/cplus/Article/9857/0/page/2

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683500(v=vs.85).aspx

my source code is almost exact copy of above examples except that before creating
SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY and calling StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(ServiceTable) I have called the function which Installs the service.

The service Installs correctly but never starts running, infact ServiceMain is never called.

Environment:
Windows 7 64-bit
Lnaguage C++
Visual Studio 2008

Comment: Can you see your services listed in the Services window?  What happens when you try and start it?

Comment: yes it gets listed in Services window.
when I tried to start it through Services window , it gave
"Error 1053 : the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least based on the code you've linked, you have a ServiceMain, and (presumably in `main`) you call `CreateService`.

The step you seem to be missing is a call to [`StartService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686321.aspx) after you call `CreateService`.